# hammer.js 2.0 not returning event options when using jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, hammer.js, swipe-gesture

I am using hammer.js to navigate a rotating menu using panstart/panend. I need to get the distance of the pan and this works correctly when using the following code (and logs distance/deltax/direction as expected):

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('footer');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
mc.on("panstart panend", function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.type);
    if(ev.type=='panend')
    {
        console.log('distance: ' + ev.distance);
        console.log('delta x: ' + ev.deltaX);
        console.log('direction: ' + ev.direction);
    }
});
```

However when i use the following code (with the hammer jquery script included) then i get the ev.type logged correctly but the distance/deltax/direction are all undefined:

```
$('#wrapper').hammer().on("panstart panend", "#footer", function(ev){
    console.log(ev.type);
    if(ev.type=='panend')
    {
        console.log('distance: ' + ev.distance);
        console.log('delta x: ' + ev.deltaX);
        console.log('direction: ' + ev.direction);
    }
});
```

I can't see why this would be the case as the code is identical and it's firing the correct ev.type event when using jquery. Can anyone explain how I get the distance etc when using jquery (I need to use it on dynamically added elements hence why i'm using the jquery plugin)?

Thanks everyone,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Add `.gesture` to your `ev.distance/deltaX/direction` console log commands:

```
$('#wrapper').hammer().on("panstart panend", "#footer", function(ev){
    console.log(ev.type);
    if(ev.type=='panend')
    {
        console.log('distance: ' + ev.gesture.distance);
        console.log('delta x: ' + ev.gesture.deltaX);
        console.log('direction: ' + ev.gesture.direction);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you add a description of how this resolves the problem?